# Java: Bank account transatcion limit -> How to represent that there is no limit for some accounts?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a quick question about representing single transaction limits for bank accounts. I have different types of bank accounts where each one has a certain single transaction limit. However, **some** of these **account types** have **no transaction limit**. I could come up with a pretty simple solution which just uses a constant to indicate that (see example below).

```
private static final double NO_TRANSACTION_LIMIT = -1;  

public enum BankAccountType {
    GIRO_MINOR(0, 20, "Minor Account"),
    GIRO_STUDENT(0, 200, "Student Account"),
    GIRO_NORMAL(-2000, 4000, "Normal Account"),
    SAVING(0, NO_TRANSACTION_LIMIT, "Saving Account");
    // ...
    private double transactionLimit;
    // ...
    public boolean hasTransactionLimit() {
        return transactionLimit == NO_TRANSACTION_LIMIT;
    }
}
```

After some thinking, I thought there must be a better solution to that problem. Because if for some reason the method `hasTransactionLimit()` is not checked before a transaction limit, this might cause unwanted behavior.
So my question: **what is a good strategy to implement behavior like that?** Somehow I thought of the Null-Object pattern, but I am pretty unsure.

Comment: One possibility that comes to mind would actually be the [Strategy-Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Each account could have a `TransactionLimitStrategy` that is checked when the `Transaction` is executed (for this, the transaction would need to have a final `execute(...)` method that checks the validity of itself w.r.t. the strategy).

Comment: That´s a really good idea. I´ll try how it works out and hopefully do not forget to reply. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an interface `BankAccount` with a method `isTransactionAllowed(int amount)` instead of using an enum that returns a transation limit.

Because what you want to do with your enum is to execute type specific code. That's why the enum is named `...Type`. In an object oriented language like java you should do this using polymorphism.

E.g.

```
public interface BankAccount {
    public boolean isTransactionAllowed(int amount);
}
```

And the concrete bank account can answer this question. Either statically or based on it's actual state. E.g. a limit of 200 is allowed within 10 days or this bank account allows a transaction limit of 200 while all other of this type only allow 100.

E.g. statically:

```
public class MinorBankAccount implements BankAccount {

    private static final int MINOR_ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION_LIMIT = 20;

    public boolean isTransactionAllowed(int amount) {
        return amount <= MINOR_ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION_LIMIT;
    }

}
```

What you do is usually a hint for an anemic design. For more details take a look at my blog [Enums as type discriminator anti-pattern](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2015/12/03/enums-as-type-discriminator-anti-pattern/)